# Copy-paste using Capybara?

Tags: selenium, capybara, copy-paste

I would love to do something like this:

```
div = find '#some-div'
copy_to_clipboard(div)

input = find '#my-input'
paste_from_clipboard(input)
```

I do not want to simulate this with `send_keys` and using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V; I want this to work cross-browser (especially on mobile).

Does this API exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Capybara copy/paste API -  If all you want to do is copy the visible text into an input then you could do

```
div_text = find('#some-div').text()
find('#my-input').set(div_text)
```

If that's not correct for what you want, then you could use #execute_script to create a selection range like

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart( <start node>, <start node character offset> );
range.setEnd( <end node>, <end node character offset> ); 

window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
```

then find your target element and set it's value to window.getSelection().toString().  Note that's not really emulating what a user would do, so if you are actually using this for testing an app I would still recommend using the ctrl/cmd-c/v after setting the selection range for browsers that support it since it emulates user behavior better.

Comment: Thanks. This confirmed my suspicion—there is no Capybara copy/paste API.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way I've found:

```
element.send_keys [:control, 'c']
element.send_keys [:control, 'v']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old one, however you don't need to use `capybara` however the workaround would to use this incredibly simple gem:

https://github.com/janlelis/clipboard

Answer (score -2):

There is no API to do it.

**You can get element from one browser**

```
div = page.find('#some-div')
```

**Then you can pass it to another browser**

```
fill_in '#some-other-div' with => div
```

You can read more about capybara here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara