# Emulating a clipboard copy/paste with Selinum + Capybara

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a "Copy Link" button in my frontend UI. When clicked, the URL inside an input box is copied to the user's clipboard with this JS:

```
const copyTextarea = document.querySelector("#copy-link-button");
copyTextarea.focus();
copyTextarea.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
```

When I try it out locally, this functionality works perfectly so I know the feature itself is working correctly.

However I'm unable to test the copy with Capybara. I know from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34818563/10252006) that Capybara does not provide a clipboard API, but my workaround is to -

1. Copy the link using the "Copy Link" button
2. Navigate to some other input/text field
3. Paste into the field with CTRL+V and read the contents of the field to verify

My test:

```
# Copy the link
page.find("#copy-link-button").click
wait_for_ajax

# Visit some other page that I know has an input/text field
visit account_settings_path

input = page.find("#user_email")

# Clear the field
fill_in("user[email]", with: "")

# Paste in the contents of the clipboard
input.base.send_keys([:control, "v"])

# Validate
expect(input.value).to eq("some value");
```

However nothing gets pasted into that input (`input.value` and `input.text` return `""`).

Is this a valid approach? Is the issue here with copying the text in the first place or did I make an error in pasting the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: since the original posting of this Chrome has changed the available permission types. For the headless solution go to https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#type-PermissionType to see what permission types are currently available

---

There are lots of security rules around access to the clipboard content, so trying to get paste working from Capybara is really going to be an exercise in frustration. Additionally most browsers won't actually do anything when ctrl/command v is sent as a keystroke since it's a system triggered action not the browser.

However, since you just want to verify the copy works you don't actually need to trigger the paste, you just need to get around the permission requirements to use the clipboard API. If you're using Chrome (in a non-headless configuration - doesn't currently work headless) you can do that by setting the `profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard` preference in your driver registration

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_preference('profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard', {
    '*': {'setting': 1}
  })
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end
```

If you are running in headless mode and using up-to-date Capybara and selenium with Chrome another option is to use CDP to grant the permissions

```
page.driver.browser.execute_cdp('Browser.grantPermissions', origin: page.server_url, permissions: ['clipboardRead', 'clipboardWrite'])
```

Once you have the permissions worked out you can then use `evaluate_async_script` to access the clipboard data

```
clip_text = page.evaluate_async_script('navigator.clipboard.readText().then(arguments[0])')
```

Notes:

1. there is no need to use `base` to call `send_keys` on an element, just call it on the element
2. `expect(input.value).to eq("some value")` will lead to flaky tests, instead you should use the Capybara provided matchers like `expect(page).to have_field(with: 'some value')` or `expect(input).to match_selector(:field, with: 'some value')`

Comment: This is really useful, thank you! I'm running headless chrome so will try the latter

Comment: Thank you!  Worked great with regular `chrome` driver; however, as of Sept 2020, headless chrome is throwing this at me: `invalid argument: Unknown permission type: clipboardRead (Session info: headless chrome=84.0.4147.125)`

Comment: @danielricecodes That's the thing about using bleeding edge functionality -- it gets changed.  You can see the currently supported permission types at https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#type-PermissionType - you probably want 'clipboardReadWrite'

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I just came back to edit my comment when I saw yours!  Yes, the permissions have indeed merged.  Just using `clipboardReadWrite` works perfectly!

Comment: Solution working great in 2021! With slightly changes mentioned by @danielricecodes

Comment: When I try the line for `page.evaluate_async_script` I get an error of class `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ScriptTimeoutError`. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind -- I got it to work by avoiding these steps in a `binding.pry` debug session. Working with cdp is best avoided in that type of irb environment I guess. Thank you for all the help here!!!!!