# How to use clipboard functions in headless chrome for capybara and selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, headless-browser

I tried the following solution

[Emulating a clipboard copy/paste with Selinum + Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034127/emulating-a-clipboard-copy-paste-with-selinum-capybara)

but getting `` NoMethodError: undefined method `execute_cdp' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x000055851220xxxx> ``

My versions

ruby - 2.4.10
selenium webdriver - 3.6
capybara 3.32.2
chrome browser - 74

new to capybara automation. any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade everything to current versions and things will work for you.  Ruby 2.4 went EOL over a year ago, selenium-webdriver 3.6 is 4 years old, Chrome 74 is over two years old, capybara 3.32 is over a year old,